# Discovery Interface not found

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio-2013, argumentexception

The Discovery Client code.

```
var dc = new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
FindCriteria fc = new FindCriteria(typeof(IService1));
fc.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
FindResponse fr = dc.Find(fc);
```

I am hosting the wcf and I have been able to check and see it working using my own implementation of discovery but I have been informed this was is faster and more secure. I'm not sure why i get the following error message though.

```
System.ArgumentException occurred
Message: A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Interface not found.
```

Any ideas on how I could fix this?

It turns out I can run the code and it works from the .exe but it doesn't work when I run in visual studio debugger.

Comment: Iservice1 interface is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the symbols were not loading when I was in debug mode